# Magento 1 script to get customers wishlist

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, script

I want to create a script to get a list of all customers and their items inside their wishlist.

How can we achieve this in our Magento 1.9.4.1 store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
$mod = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->getCollection();
$data_wishlist = array();
foreach($mod as $data)
{
    $item_array = array();
    $load = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->load($data->getId())->getItemCollection();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($data->getCustomerId());
    $count = 0;
    foreach($load as $item)
    {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
        $item_array[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'product_name' => $product->getName(),
            'qty_ordered' => $item->getQty(),
            'stock_available' => $stockItem->getIsInStock()
        );
        $count++;
    }
    if($count){
        $data_wishlist[] = array(
            'customer_id' => $data->getCustomerId(),
            'customer_email' => $customer->getEmail(),
            'customer_name' => $customer->getFirstname() .' '. $customer->getLastname(),
            'last_update' => $data->getUpdatedAt(),
            'item_list' => $item_array
        );
    };
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data_wishlist);
```